# upgrade 1.8 to 1.9.4

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

Anyone know best practice to go from **CE 1.8** to **CE 1.9.4** ?
I ran these:

```
chmod 750 mage
./mage mage-setup .
./mage config-set preferred_state stable
./mage sync
./mage install https://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
```

But got a

> fatal error. Unknown function: is_dir_writeable().

Comment: What PHP version do you use?

Comment: PHP version is 5.6.4